# How to embed PDF from a document library using XSLT

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am attempting using the XSLT List View webpart to display the most recent PDF file uploaded to a Document library.

The idea is that a specific user uploads a PDF file for a monthly newsletter to a Document Library. I have a View set up to display one item (the most recent item).

I can get it to work by specifying the entire path to the file as such:

```
<xsl:template match="Item">
<div class="item">
<object data="https://example.com/subsite/Documents/file.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="700px" height="550px">
<p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.</p>
</object>
</div>
</xsl:template>
```

However I am hoping to enter the URL as something like this:

```
"https://example.com/subsite/Documents/<xsl:value-of select='Name'/>"
```

I am unable to enter the XSL tag within the html Object tag.

Any suggestions?

Martin

Comment: I am sending a E-mail using xslt file. If i want to attach a pdf file with that E-mail,then how can i attach ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took some days off from work and returned with a fresh mind to this task. I was ale to achieve the desired results by adding an additional column to the document library for users to enter the file name. Then used XSL attributes as follows:

```
<object type="application/pdf" width="700px" height="550px">
    <xsl:attribute name="data">
            <xsl:text>/Site/Documents/</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="File" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser. Please contact the help desk.</p>
</object>
```

Extra step for the users but they will have to deal with that inconvenience for now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything else is correct in your web part, it should be a matter of doing this:

```
data="https://example.com/subsite/Documents/{@Name}"
```

Personally, I use a data view web part instead of XSLT list views because I get total control of what I'm doing and the rendered output. If doing the above doesn't work, it could be converted to a dataview web part and then it should work with the `data="https://example.com/subsite/Documents/{@Name}"` piece.

Comment: Almost works. Stays "Initializing" but never loads the PDF. Unfortunately, XSLT List Viewer is all I have access to.

Comment: Made a small change, was derping a bit there not including the full URL.

Answer (score 0):

1- Created library app
2- Uploaded PDF
3- Opened PDF within browser
4- Copied link

And pasted it here:

```
<object>type="application/pdf"
```

It worked